# Query is working fine in query browser but not in python code

Tags: python, sql, pandas, teradata

I have a teradata sql query which is working fine in Teradata Studio Express's query browser but when I tried to run the same query in my python code I am getting following error:

> (3706, "[42000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver]Teradata
>   DatabaseSyntax error: expected something between '(' and
>   '('.")

My query:

```
td_query = """select 
hash_md5((XMLAGG(TRIM(h_age) ORDER BY h_age ASC) (VARCHAR(100))) )hash_age,
hash_md5((XMLAGG(TRIM(h_marks) ORDER BY h_age ASC )(VARCHAR(100)))) hash_marks,
hash_md5((XMLAGG(TRIM(h_id) ORDER BY h_age ASC )(VARCHAR(100)))) hash_id,
hash_md5((XMLAGG(TRIM(h_score) ORDER BY h_age ASC )(VARCHAR(100))))hash_score,
hash_md5((XMLAGG(TRIM(h_name) ORDER BY h_age ASC )(VARCHAR(100))))hash_name,
hash_md5((XMLAGG(TRIM(h_entry) ORDER BY h_entry ASC )(VARCHAR(100))))hash_entry,
SUM(Aggrownum) sum_val,
COUNT(Aggrownum) count_val,
sum_val/count_val row_num
from 
(
Select 
hash_md5(CAST(age AS VARCHAR(100)))h_age ,
hash_md5(CAST(marks AS VARCHAR(100)))h_marks,
hash_md5(CAST(id AS VARCHAR(100)))h_id,
hash_md5(CAST(score AS VARCHAR(100)))h_score,
hash_md5(CAST(f_name AS VARCHAR(100)))h_name,
hash_md5(CAST(entry AS FORMAT 'yyyy-mm-ddbhh:mi:ss') (char (20)))h_entry,
row_number() over (partition by dob order by  age asc) rno,round(rno/500.0) Aggrownum
from tdwm.student_2
) A group by Aggrownum ORDER BY row_num;
"""
```

and in python file running it as:

```
df_teradata = pd.read_sql(td_query, connect)
```

Where `connect` is the `td.UdaExec` object and above code is working fine for other simpler queries such as `select * from tdwm.student_2`.

I also tried minimized version of the same query I am getting the same error.

This is the code where I'm using `td_query`:

```
import pandas as pd
import teradata as td

td_host, td_username, td_passwd, td_dbname = '10.20.181.55', 'dbac', 'dbac', 'tdwm'

udaExec = td.UdaExec(appName="test", version="1.0", logConsole=False)
with udaExec.connect(method="odbc",system=td_host, username=td_username, port=1025,
                            password=td_passwd, driver="Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.20") as connect:
    df_teradata = pd.read_sql(td_query, connect)
```

Comment: try to escape the double quotes (")  like this  \"

Comment: @user4321 but there is no `"` in the query. Or do you mean `\"""select `?

Comment: Seems like the parser doesn't find the `hash_md5` UDF. The submitting user might have a different default database.

Comment: @dnoeth so can I send query to the `teradata` server **without parsing it first in python**?

Comment: why do you have what appears to be three sets of double quotes around your query string? When you say this works in Teradata Studio, are you including all those double quotes there?

Comment: @Andrew No, I do not include these `"""` while running the query there. Even if I give one `"` instead of three the issue persists.

Comment: I'd suggest printing out your `td_query` variable in python.  Copy that, see if it executes in TD Studio.

Comment: @Andrew ... the triple double quote is a Python multi-line string or comment. Those quotes do not appear inside string.

Comment: @Parfait added the related code please check

Comment: What is `td`? Please include `import` lines. And did you test exact query in Studio Express with `dbac` user on server at `10.20.181.55`? And check under what db/schema `hash_mdf5()` stored function exists and if `dbac` has access to it.

Comment: @Parfait I have posted the updated code and yes this query works with Studio Express with dbac user on server at 10.20.181.55

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced similar issue..

The issue with your query is that it contains `hash_md5` function which is unknown to `teradata python module`, that's why the error.

Solution:

Add database name before that function (like you have done before table name `tdwm.student_2`). So your new query will be:

```
select 
 tdwm.hash_md5((XMLAGG(TRIM(h_age) ORDER BY h_age ASC) (VARCHAR(100))) )hash_age,
 tdwm.hash_md5((XMLAGG(TRIM(h_marks) ORDER BY h_age ASC )(VARCHAR(100)))) hash_marks,
 tdwm.hash_md5((XMLAGG(TRIM(h_id) ORDER BY h_age ASC )(VARCHAR(100)))) hash_id,
 tdwm.hash_md5((XMLAGG(TRIM(h_score) ORDER BY h_age ASC )(VARCHAR(100))))hash_score,
 tdwm.hash_md5((XMLAGG(TRIM(h_name) ORDER BY h_age ASC )(VARCHAR(100))))hash_name,
 tdwm.hash_md5((XMLAGG(TRIM(h_entry) ORDER BY h_entry ASC )(VARCHAR(100))))hash_entry,
 SUM(Aggrownum) sum_val,
 COUNT(Aggrownum) count_val,
 sum_val/count_val row_num
 from 
 (
 Select 
  tdwm.hash_md5(CAST(age AS VARCHAR(100)))h_age ,
  tdwm.hash_md5(CAST(marks AS VARCHAR(100)))h_marks,
  tdwm.hash_md5(CAST(id AS VARCHAR(100)))h_id,
  tdwm.hash_md5(CAST(score AS VARCHAR(100)))h_score,
  tdwm.hash_md5(CAST(f_name AS VARCHAR(100)))h_name,
  tdwm.hash_md5(CAST(entry AS FORMAT 'yyyy-mm-ddbhh:mi:ss') (char (20)))h_entry,
 row_number() over (partition by dob order by  age asc) rno,round(rno/500.0) Aggrownum
 from tdwm.student_2
 ) A group by Aggrownum ORDER BY row_num;
```